# Compiler complain about “opcode_table undeclared (first use in this function)", why?

Tags: c

I have this function:

```
void run(int PC)
{
    int A = 0, op = 0, arg = 0, i = 0;
    char *xpress = NULL, *acode = NULL, strarg[CL_ARG_SIZE];
    while (1)
      {
        printf("PC: %03x | A: %03i |", PC, A);
        op = data[PC]; arg = data[PC+1];
        PC += 2;
        for (i=0 ; i<21 ; ++i)
             if (op == opcode_table[i].op)
             {
                 acode = opcode_table[i].mnemo;
                 sprintf(strarg, "0x%x", arg);   
                 xpress = replace(opcode_table[i].instruct, "_", strarg);
                 break;
              }
         printf(" %s %x\t| %s \t", acode, arg, xpress);
         step();
         exec_instruct(op, arg, &A, &PC);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile my program I get the following errors:

> :103:35: error:‘opcode_table’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   :103:35: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three lines of code in your function where you use the array variable `opcode_table` without declaring it first. Starting with:

```
if (op == opcode_table[i].op)
```

Comment: @Yoan15 - You need to understand what this program is doing, and how.

Comment: I understand what the program is doing but i have problem to declare the variable opcode_table

Comment: Can someone help me to resolve this problem please ?

Comment: As written, your question is impossible to answer. I suggest you post another one, including MCVE and concrete problem.

Comment: My concrete problem is the declaration of the variable opcode_table in this function. How can i declare: (op == opcode_table[i].op) ?